# Common JSP in all portlet

Tags: portlet, liferay-6

We are having multiple portlets in our portal, we need to include a common JSP in each of the  portlet.
This JSP needs to access the custom services in the JSP, for that we are having the service jar in \liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.27\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\lib .

So, whats the process of getting this accomplished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a hook and place your jsp under html/common/ or any other directory of your choice and having your common code of calling custom service. This jsp can then be include using <%@ include file="/html/common/custom.jsp" %>